# Reading attribute value from XML column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I extract the value of the attribute from the XML data?

```
drop table #demo2
create table #demo2 (field1 xml)
insert into #demo2 (field1) 
values (
'<root xmlns="system/schema" vesion="1.0">
    <header msgtype="1">
        <msgid>1</msgid>
    </header>
    <transaction>
        <systemevent>
            <eventdetail eventtype="100">
                <eventstamp unitid="87888" value="2021-11-14T01:44:41.069Z" />
                <eventitem id="1" value="abc123" />
            </eventdetail>
            <eventdetail eventtype="102">
                <eventstamp unitid="87889" value="2021-11-14T01:44:41.704Z" />
                <eventitem id="2" />
            </eventdetail>
        </systemevent>
    </transaction>
</root>')
```

I am expecting the answer to be `abc123` & `null` for this XML. Below is the query I tried to get my expected value.

```
select  x.v.value('@value','VARCHAR(100)') AS EventValue,
        y.v.value('@value','VARCHAR(100)') AS EventValue2
from #demo2 t
cross apply field1.nodes('//eventdetail[@eventtype="100"]/eventitem') x(v)
cross apply field1.nodes('//eventdetail[@eventtype="102"]/eventitem') y(v)
```

I am not sure what is missing in my `xpath` to get the value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

`<root xmlns="system/schema" vesion="1.0">`

means that the document has a [default namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/managing-namespaces-in-an-xml-document#declaration-scope), and so all the elements are actually in the namespace.  That document is equivilent to this one:

```
<foo:root xmlns:foo="system/schema" vesion="1.0">
  <foo:header msgtype="1">
    <foo:msgid>1</foo:msgid>
  </foo:header>
  <foo:transaction>
    <foo:systemevent>
      <foo:eventdetail eventtype="100">
        <foo:eventstamp unitid="87888" value="2021-11-14T01:44:41.069Z" />
        <foo:eventitem id="1" value="abc123" />
      </foo:eventdetail>
      <foo:eventdetail eventtype="102">
        <foo:eventstamp unitid="87889" value="2021-11-14T01:44:41.704Z" />
        <foo:eventitem id="2" />
      </foo:eventdetail>
    </foo:systemevent>
  </foo:transaction>
</foo:root>
```

so you must namespace-qualify your query with [WITH XMLNAMESPACES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=%20WITH%20XMLNAMESPACES%20%28Transact-SQL%29%20provides%20namespace%20URI%20support,of%20the%20xml%20Data%20Type%20Methods.%20More%20), eg

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'system/schema')  
select  x.v.value('@value','VARCHAR(100)') AS EventValue,
        y.v.value('@value','VARCHAR(100)') AS EventValue2
from #demo2 t
cross apply field1.nodes('//eventdetail[@eventtype="100"]/eventitem') x(v)
cross apply field1.nodes('//eventdetail[@eventtype="102"]/eventitem') y(v)
```

And you should also fully-qualify the element XPath instead of using `//` in most cases.  EG

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'system/schema')  
select  x.v.value('@value','VARCHAR(100)') AS EventValue,
        y.v.value('@value','VARCHAR(100)') AS EventValue2
from #demo2 t
cross apply field1.nodes('/root/transaction/systemevent/eventdetail[@eventtype="100"]/eventitem') x(v)
cross apply field1.nodes('/root/transaction/systemevent/eventdetail[@eventtype="102"]/eventitem') y(v)
```